# fetch the hidden text and put it within a div tag

Tags: jquery

When an anchor tag is clicked, "anotherDiv" is made visible.

Using jQuery, I want to be able to fetch the description within each li onClick of the anchor tag and insert it into the "anotherDiv" area which is also visible onClick of an anchor tag. The description text is initially set to display none.

```
<style>
    .desc{
     display:none;
    }

    #anotherDiv{
       display: none;
    }

</style>

        <li style="overflow: hidden; float: none; width: 158px; height: 125px;">
                    <a onClick="return addPlayer(952541791001, 661361792001, 600, 320)" id="no8" class="video-pop">
                        <img width="132" height="75" alt="" src="image.jpg">
                    </a>
                    <div class="label">The label goes here......</div>
                    <div class="desc">The description goes here.....</div>
                </li>
      <li style="overflow: hidden; float: none; width: 158px; height: 125px;">
                    <a onClick="return addPlayer(952541791001, 661361792001, 600, 320)" id="no10" class="video-pop">
                        <img width="132" height="75" alt="" src="image.jpg">
                    </a>
                    <div class="label">The label goes here......</div>
                    <div class="desc">The description goes here.....</div>
                </li>
    -------------------------------------------------------------
    <div id="anotherDiv"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
http://jsfiddle.net/MZga6/

```
$('a').bind('click.myClick', function() {
    var that = $(this);
  $('#anotherDiv').text(that.parent().find('.desc').text()).show();

});
```

Comment: Make sure you post your code in your answers. That way future visitors can benefit from your knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

When list item is clicked, get child description. Then insert its html in anotherDiv.

```
$('li').click( function() {
     $('#anotherDiv').html($(this).children('.desc').html());
});

//a more readable format to help you understand
$('li').click( function() {
     //$this is the clicked list item. We search its children for class `desc` and get contents
     var desc = $(this).children('.desc').html();
     //set anotherDiv's contents
     $('#anotherDiv').html(desc);
});
```

Comment: It returns empty when I try to display a hidden element.So I should be able to make the text visible first and then insert into anotherDiv.

Comment: @web_dev - that's because your anotherDiv is hidden. You can show it with `show` or to be cool use `fadeIn` or `slideDown`.